# Add items to an existing list mvc5

Tags: list, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdown, addition

(I am a new developer)I have a list that I put in a viewBag to make a dropwdown in my view and I would like to add 3 elements to this list so that we can see them at the end of my dropdown. I make a timesheet for the employees and I have a dropdown of the projects that the person worked during the week and I would like to add at the end of the dropdown the 3 options "Vacancy", "Unplanned Absence", "Planned Absence" if the person has been on leave instead of working.

This is my request for the projects :

```
var projectAssignment = (from pa in db.ProjectAssignment
                                     join p in db.Projects on pa.ProjectId equals p.ID
                                     where pa.EmployeeId == EmployeeId && pa.StartDate !=null && (pa.EndDate == null || pa.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
                                     select new ProjectTimesheetList
                                     {
                                         ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
                                         ProjectId = pa.ProjectId
                                     });
ViewBag.ProjectTimeSHeet = projectAssignment;
```

This is a the modal to add my timehseet [image]and i want to put the 3 daysoff type at the end of dropdown, so in this case after "NatureBooker"

And this is my code of my dropdown:

```
<select name="' + row + '_' + col + '" class="custom-select" id="tsCell_' + row + '_' + col + '" data-row="' + row + '" data-col="' + col + '">' +
                    '<option value="">----Select----</option>@Html.Raw(projsStr)</select>';
```

SOLUTION:

```
var projectAssignment = (from pa in db.ProjectAssignment
                                     join p in db.Projects on pa.ProjectId equals p.ID
                                     where pa.EmployeeId == EmployeeId && pa.StartDate !=null && (pa.EndDate == null || pa.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
                                     select new ProjectTimesheetList
                                     {
                                         ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
                                         ProjectId = pa.ProjectId
                                     });

            List<ProjectTimesheetList> projectAssignments = projectAssignment.ToList();

            projectAssignments.Add(new ProjectTimesheetList
            {
                ProjectName = "Vacancy",
                ProjectId = -1,
            });

            projectAssignments.Add(new ProjectTimesheetList
            {
                ProjectName = "Unplanned Absence",
                ProjectId = -2,
            });

            projectAssignments.Add(new ProjectTimesheetList
            {
                ProjectName = "Planned Absence",
                ProjectId = -3,
            });

            ViewBag.ProjectTimeSHeet = projectAssignments;
```

And the result: [image]

Comment: What is the question?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: @Duston No, this query works, but I don't know how to add the 3 dayoff options I want, that is: "Vacancy", "Unplanned Absence", "Planned Absence". So example I want to see in my dropdown: project 1- project 2 project 3, Vacancy, Unplanned Absence, Planned Absence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not clear what exactly you want, but if my guess is right you probably want to add "fake" projects to the enumerable you're binding to (not a list, by the way).

As long as you understand that this is absolutely wrong and grounds for being fired on the spot, here you go:

```
ViewBag.ProjectTimeSHeet = projectAssignment
    .Concat(new[]
        {
            new ProjectTimesheetList
            {
                ProjectName = "Vacancy",
                ProjectId = -1,
            },
            new ProjectTimesheetList
            {
                ProjectName = "Unplanned Absence",
                ProjectId = -2,
            },
            new ProjectTimesheetList
            {
                ProjectName = "Planned Absence",
                ProjectId = -3,
            },
        });
```

Comment: The view bag variable misspelling is yours, and you chose a great place for it, in a dynamic variable with no compile-time check.

Comment: Yes basically that's what I want, but I don't understand your last sentence "As long as you understand that this is absolutely wrong and grounds for being fired on the spot, here you go:" haha?

Comment: i have this error : Unable to create a constant value of type 'XXX.Models.ProjectTimesheetList'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: I would need to see the code that gives that error, the code you've shown so far (which is basically nothing) seems to indicate my code should work.

Comment: And I wasn't joking, not only is this entire pattern wrong, it also shows your database is set up without foreign keys which would otherwise fail on these fake IDs. This is a lack of fundamental understanding of relational database design, and the fact that the MVC brings it to light is a plus for MVC itself.

Comment: i have this error when i do your code : ViewBag.ProjectTimeSHeet = projectAssignment
    .Concat(new[]
        {
            new ProjectTimesheetList
            {
                ProjectName = "Vacancy",
                ProjectId = -1,
            },
            new ProjectTimesheetList
            {
                ProjectName = "Unplanned Absence",
                ProjectId = -2,
            },
            new ProjectTimesheetList
            {
                ProjectName = "Planned Absence",
                ProjectId = -3,
            },
        });

Comment: Yes I know what I wrote, didn't need a copy and paste, I don't know **your** code and where you're introducing this so-called error.

Comment: I published the solution in my post, I no longer have the error I had that way. Thanks for giving me 95% of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myOptions = {
    val1 : 'Vacancy',
    val2 : 'Unplanned Absence',
    val3 : 'Planned Absence',
};
var mySelect = $('#dropdownID');
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});
```

through Javascript

```
  var ddl = document.getElementById("dropdownID");
   for ( let key in myOptions ) 
   {
        var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        option.innerHTML = key
        option.value = myOptions[key]
        ddl.options.add(option);
    }
```

Comment: The Question is still unclear. if you don't want to add more items on front end then please Provide more Details what exactly you want?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I modified my message and I added an image of what I want, but I will try with the code that you sent, see what it gives as a result